# Is it possible to use a chunk of observations instead of one observation in Recursive Least Squares (RLS) at once?

Tags: regression, recursive-algorithms, linear-regression, filters, kalman-filter

Recursive Least Squares (RLS) by its structure reestimates coefficients iteratively utilizing one new observation in each iteration. Is it possible to use $n$ new observations in one iteration to reestimate coefficients?
Perhaps some similar to RLS method can handle it?

Of course, executing $n$ RLS steps (iterations) sequentially gives the result, but if $n$ is relatively big, utilizing a chunk of observations in one iteration can be more computationally efficient.

Comment: What kind of RLS are considering? For example, if you are using a forgetting factor a question would be if you still want older measurements to have a smaller weight?

Comment: Let's assume I don't use the forgetting factor for the first case. I know forgetting can be harder in such "chunk" approach.

Comment: I think it is possible to use the batch of measurements as a single measurement vector. Though, this would change the square matrix to be a lot bigger. Maybe with some assumptions it might be possible to decompose that matrix as a lower rank matrix.